# How can I GROUP BY on a partial field?

Tags: t-sql, group-by

Hello I have table in my database holding some browser information I'm currently using the following T-SQL to get a summary list:

```
SELECT Browser, Version, SUM(Count) as Count FROM AnalyticsBrowsers
WHERE Month=8 AND Year=2011
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%YandexBot%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%Googlebot%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%Yahoo! Slurp%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%Exabot%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%Ezooms%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%facebookexternalhit%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%YPBot%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%Nutraspace%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%AhrefsBot%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%Gigabot%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%GT::WWW%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%WGet%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%cmsworldmap%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%CatchBot%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%SuperPages%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%msnbot%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%nutch%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%Yeti%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%Curl%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%Mediapartners-Google%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%Python-urllib%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%AC-BaiduBot%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%MLBot%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%YahooCacheSystem%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%Xenu%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE '%DoCoMo%'
AND UserAgent NOT LIKE 'Content Crawler'
GROUP BY Browser, Version
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

Its not overly pretty but its working so far. I'm getting results that look like:

```
Browser            Version      Count
Mozilla            5.0          804
IE                 8.0          738
AppleMAC-Safari    5.0          429
IE                 7.0          371
IE                 6.0          271
Firefox            6.0          189
IE                 9.0          137
Firefox            5.0          68
Firefox            3.6.20       42
Firefox            3.6.10       33
Firefox            4.0.1        20
Unknown            0.0          17
Firefox            3.6.18       10
Firefox            5.0.1        9
Mozilla            1.9.2.20     8
Firefox            3.6.13       6
Opera              9.80         6
Firefox            3.6.3        5
Firefox            3.6.12       4
Opera              9.24         4
IE                 5.5          4
Mozilla            1.9.2.16     3
Firefox            3.6.21       3
Firefox            3.6.6        3
Firefox            3.6.8        3
Firefox            4.0          3
Mozilla            4.0          3
Firefox            3.5.19       3
```

What do I need to do to my T-SQL to combine versions with the same major and minor version number, regardless of what the other build numbers are? For example I would like these to all be grouped together as Version 3.6

```
Firefox            3.6.20       42
Firefox            3.6.10       33
Firefox            3.6.18       10
Firefox            3.6.13       6
Firefox            3.6.3        5
Firefox            3.6.12       4
Firefox            3.6.21       3
Firefox            3.6.6        3
Firefox            3.6.8        3
```

Comment: Just a note, Perhaps it worth to do comparison with set of known browser names instead of exclusive comparision with bot names, I believe there would be less AND  LIKE conditions

Comment: This is messy because that is a `varchar` field, so you need to do it by characters.  What if you have 2 or 3 digit version numbers?

Comment: @JNK - this is the information I am provided by C#. If I were doing this in code I would split on '.' and recombine just the 1st 2 in the resulting array and sort by that, but I would really like to keep this in SQL.

Comment: @sllev - I would much rather have an exclude list rather than an include list. there are to many possible browser types to include and the list is ever growing. I would rather bots slip into the list than miss a bew mobile browser useragent.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Do all rows have at least a major and minor version number?

Comment: @MartinSmith - 2005 SQLServer. So far all my data has a major and minor but I can't be sure that in the future I may just have a major.

Comment: @Justin - ah OK. I was mulling an entirely pointless abuse of `HierarchyId` but not an option anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty nasty, but you can replace `Version` with this expression to get all text up prior to the second decimal point:

```
LEFT(Version, CHARINDEX('.', Version + '.', CHARINDEX('.', Version) + 1) - 1)
```

This assumes each version has at least one decimal point (e.g. 1.0).

Comment: This works, and so far (a month worth of data) I don't have just a #, they are all #.# at a minimum. Is there a way to not fail on just # to be on the safe side? would changing CHARINDEX('.', Version) + 1 to CHARINDEX('.', Version + '.') + 1 solve the issue?

Comment: No, you'd have to change it to something like CHARINDEX('.', Version + '.0') + 1 to solve that issue. Need the extra character because of the "+ 1".

Comment: How about: LEFT(Version, case when CHARINDEX('.', Version) > 0 then CHARINDEX('.', Version) - 1 else LEN(Version) end)

Comment: @user92546, what happens with '3.6.3'?